# How to resolve InvalidSelectorException in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, exception

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector
```

Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression `.//*[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/span)[3]` because of the following error.

**SyntaxError:**

```
Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 
'(.//*[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/span)[3])' 
is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Comment: you will need to provide us with your HTML code too. Please avoid using absolute Xpath

Comment: (.//[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/span)[3]), you have an extra ")" right after span

Comment: the xpath has 4 matching node so that [3] requires an extra ")".

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//*[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/span)[3])').click()

Comment: Try with ((//[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/span)[3]), there seems to be a syntax error in your xpath.

Comment: @KshetraMohanPrusty same error for this xpath too.

Comment: Please share the HTML DOM of the intended area and your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The error shows that the given expression is not valid. You seem to have an extra ')' in the xpath selector at the end. So browser wouldn't have even performed the DOM selection.

Comment: Since the same xpath has 4 matching node i have used that extra ')' for using the 4th matching node.Is there any another way to do kindly help me with that.

Comment: How does adding an extra ')' help. You should be getting the 3rd span without that ')'.